# How to merge two lists of the same length, and retain the length by replacing values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two lists of binary integers:

```
mylist1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
mylist2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I would like to merge these two lists to make a new list that looks like this:

```
mylist3 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

basically changing an element in mylist2 from "0" to "1", if an element in mylist1 with the same index is a "1". So far I've tried something like this, but i know it just creates a list with all one int:

```
mylist3 = [0 if int(el) in mylist1 == int(el) in mylist2 else 1 for el in list1]
```

I'm drawing a blank here. I imagine doing a `zip` in a list comprehension may solve this maybe? Thanks for any help.

Comment: ``[sum((a,b)) for a,b in zip(mylist1,mylist2)]`` ?

Comment: What do you expect as the output if there are 1's at the same position in both lists?

Comment: Good question. In my case, the lists are being populated from user input questions in a prior block of code, and we can assume the 1 won't appear in the same place in this instance. My apologies I should've mentioned that.

Answer (score 4):

More functional approach:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import or_

mylist1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
mylist2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

result = list(starmap(or_, zip(mylist1, mylist2)))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

> `[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

---

If there are more than two values, use `max`:

```
mylist1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
mylist2 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
mylist3 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

result = list(map(max, zip(mylist1, mylist2, mylist3)))
print(result)
```

**Output:**

> `[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]`

Answer (score 3):

Could be a good use case for bitwise operators:

```
[x|y for x,y in zip(mylist1,mylist2)]

[x|y|z for x,y,z in zip(mylist1,mylist2, mylist3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
merged=[int(any([x,y])) for x,y in zip(mylist1,mylist2) ]
```

Or as  Scott Boston said, you could try with `max`:

```
merged=[max((a,b)) for a,b in zip(mylist1,mylist2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged pandas... pandas is overkill here.  but:

```
mylist1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
mylist2 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

s1 = pd.Series(mylist1, dtype='bool')
s2 = pd.Series(mylist2, dtype='bool')


(s1 | s2).astype('int').tolist()
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```